# Conflict between Using Declaration and Forward Declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, forward-declaration, using-declaration

Lets go for a walk with Bulldog :)

Say I have a namespace `Street::House` (inside namespace `Street`) where the class `Bulldog` is **declared** (let it be in `House/Bulldog.hpp`):

```
namespace Street {
namespace House {
class Bulldog {};
}
}
```

Then, I have the `Bulldog.hpp`:

```
#include "House/Bulldog.hpp"    

namespace Street {
using House::Bulldog;
}
```

Pay attention to what's going on: I'm **injecting** declaration of `Street::House::Bulldog`  to the namespace `Street` as `Street::Bulldog` with `using` declaration.

Then, I have the `Owner.hpp` where the class `Bulldog` is **forward declared**:

```
namespace Street {
class Bulldog;

class Owner {
  Bulldog* bulldog;
};
}
```

Finally, I have the `Owner.cpp`:

```
#include "Owner.hpp"
#include "Bulldog.hpp"

namespace Street {
// Implementation of Owner...
}
```

Compilation error occurs in the `Owner.cpp`:

`error: 'Bulldog' is already declared in this scope`

The natural explanation of this phenomenon seems to be that C++ treats these 2 `Bulldog` classes as different, but why? I can't see any ambiguity in this case, i.e. it could actually work if properly implemented by compilers.

What workarounds can you suggest? One I can think of is to simply remove **forward declaration** of `Bulldog` from `Owner.hpp` and move `#include "Bulldog.hpp"` from `Owner.cpp` to `Owner.hpp`. However, this will result in exact inclusion rather than **forward declaration**.

Comment: Clang has a more descriptive message `error: target of using declaration conflicts with declaration already in scope`

Comment: This is not a compiler bug, injected declarations don't work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can fix this by changing `Bulldog.hpp` to say

```
namespace Street {
    namespace House {
        class Bulldog;
    }
    using House::Bulldog;

    // ...
}
```

This works for me in Clang.

Comment: Unfortunately, now error simply moved to line 5 of your example, but that was expected as actually nothing has changed.

Comment: @Haroogan: Really? It compiled just fine for me using Clang.

Comment: @Haroogan it works fine http://ideone.com/hGNbp1 (yes, something has changed, `using House::Bulldog` is not equivalent to declaring `Bulldog` in `Street`)

Comment: @Haroogan, your original doesn't work for the same reason [(this)](http://ideone.com/uM1Ikq) doesn't work, creating a new name for a type does not change the original name; you can't forward declare `class Bulldog` if it's actually not a class but an `using`-injected or `typedef`-ed type name. It's two different namespaces (tag names and types); C++ just lets you use a tag name as a type automatically, unlike C, but they're still distinct.

Comment: (it's not exactly the same, actually, `using` is a bit different than `typedef`, but the effect is the same in this case)

Comment: OK, I got the point. The proposed solution works. Sadly, it requires to explicitly expose from which namespace `Bulldog` comes in `Owner.hpp`. Are there other facilities (except `using` and `typedef`) in C++ to avoid this? I remember I've seen a lot of injecting code in Boost.

Comment: @Haroogan not really, you can obfuscate it with templates somewhat to defer name binding but each translation unit needs some way to know what namespace names are actually declared in (rather than simply injected)...otherwise the linker would have to understand a lot more C++ than it does; namespaces are basically just a way of mangling names in a consistent way

Comment: True. I'll leave it open for a few days. Maybe someone comes up with a clever trick or remembers which technique is used in Boost (because I completely forgot in which module I saw it).

Comment: @Haroogan: Because of the way linking works, I don't think it's possible to come up with any technique that completely eliminates the ability to tell what namespace `Bulldog` comes from by inspecting the header.

Answer (score 1):

`Owner.hpp` which you wrote as:

```
namespace Street {
class Bulldog;

class Owner {
  Bulldog* bulldog;
};
}
```

Should have instead been

```
namespace Street {
namespace House {
class Bulldog;
}

class Owner {
  House::Bulldog* bulldog;
};
}
```

You were accidentally forward declaring `Street::Bulldog`, which is not a real class, instead of `Street::House::Bulldog`, which *is* a real class. Therefore, your implementation in `Owner.cpp` was upset because `Bulldog*` was ambiguous. It doesn't know if you are referring to the declared class `Street::Bulldog` or the declared (and also defined, *though the compiler doesn't care about that*) `Street::House::Bulldog`.

Since the class you wanted to forward declare is `Street::House::Bulldog`, you need to include the second, `House` namespace in your declaration in the `.hpp` file.